# windows reuse output from previous program as input in other program cmd redirect shell

Tags: c, windows, redirect, pipe, stdin

I wanna do this:
Progam1 | Program2

I wanna use the output of the first program as input(stdin) for the program2 to do some calculations.

for now this is what i have in program 2

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char userInput[100];
    int num[100];

    FILE *cmdLn = stdin;

    if (argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [<file>]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (argc == 2) {

        cmdLn = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        if (!cmdLn) {
            perror(argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    int numInput[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        fscanf(cmdLn, "%d", &numInput[i]);
        printf("%d\n", 2*numInput[i]);
    }


    if (cmdLn != stdin) {
        fclose(cmdLn);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

program 1 just creates several numbers per row. I want to use those numbers in program 2 to double them and print the result.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your program should simply read from `stdin` same way as it would from console. The shell redirection will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I am reading from with fgets from *file which is getting input from stdin

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char userInput[100];
    int numInput[100];

    FILE *file = stdin;

    if (argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [<file>]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (argc == 2) {

        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        if (!file) {
            perror(argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    int num[100];

    while (fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), file))
    {
            num[i] = atoi(userInput);
            printf("%d\n", 2*num[i]);
            i++;
        }



    if (file != stdin) {
        fclose(file);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

the shell redirection works, but not exactly how I want.
Program 1 gives me 10random int numbers.
when I get 10 different numbers from program 1 and pipe its output to program 2 I get new 10 random values and not the output of program 1 before.
program 2 should calculate those(e.g. multiply by 2).

Maybe the problem lies in program 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAXNUM 1000

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {

    char *userInput[10];
    time_t t;

    int num = atoi(argv[1]);

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", rand() % MAXNUM);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the problem is that it generates new random numbers. But I want to use the output of this program and multiply it with 2 with program 2

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it! Yeehawww!
It was the srand() causing this problem. Uncommenting that solved it.